# random forest regressor coefficient

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I write a regression model of random forest in panda.
I got that result-

explained_variance:  0.3134
mean_squared_log_error:  0.7102
r2:  0.3132
MAE:  7.014
MSE:  135.231
RMSE:  11.6289

I want to see what are the coefficient of the model (or another code that give result like summery).
I search in the interest and didn't found.

can someone know how to get this ?

Comment: What kind of coefficients are you looking for? Trees don't have coefficients like, let's say, linear regression. Instead they have feature importances.

Comment: I need a classification model, but I cant use linear regression because I need not binary results. Also at my work they work with SQL there for I cant run the model on all the data. There for I took a small part from the data to run it on the model ( at Collab panda) . My target is to take the coefficient and put them on a query in SQL to run it on all the data.